# How to draw the bounding box of a brep entity on viewport?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I'd like to draw the bounding box of a selected entity. I can have it done by drawing line by line, however, I see it offer the BoundingBox but I cannot get it to work. I am not sure how it can add the `box` to `theModel` so it can be drawn.

```
 theModel.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
             {
                 foreach(var selecteditem in e.AddedItems)
                     if(selecteditem.Item is Entity entity)
                         selectedEntities.Add(entity);

                 foreach (var selecteditem in e.RemovedItems)
                     if (selecteditem.Item is Entity entity)
                         selectedEntities.Remove(entity);

                 foreach(var ent in selectedEntities)
                 {
                     if(ent is Brep brep)
                     {
                         brep = (Brep)ent;
                        var box = new BoundingBox(font, 6666, true, false, brep.BoxMin, brep.BoxMax);
                     }
                 }
                 
                 theModel.Invalidate();
            
             };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BoundingBox class is designed only for the [Model's bounding box settings](http://documentation.devdept.com/2020/topic_0000000000001231.html).

Comment: Thanks and it makes sense and there are not many use cases that we need to turn on bounding box for every entity.